# plot with polycollection disappears when polygons get too small

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a `PolyCollection` to plot data of various sizes. Sometimes the polygons are very small. If they are too small, they don't get plotted at all. I would expect the outline at least to show up so you'd have an idea that some data is there. Is there a a setting to control this?

Here's some code to reproduce the problem, as well as the output image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib import colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
verts = []

edge_col = colors.colorConverter.to_rgb('lime')
face_col = [(2.0 + val) / 3.0 for val in edge_col] # a little lighter

for i in range(10):
    w = 0.5 * 10**(-i)
    xs = [i - w, i - w, i + w, i - w]
    ys = [-w, w, 0, -w]

    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))

ax.set_xlim(-1, 11)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

ax.add_collection(PolyCollection(verts, lw=3, alpha=0.5, edgecolor=edge_col, facecolor=face_col))

plt.savefig('out.png')
```

[image: out]

Notice that only six polygons are visible, whereas there should be ten.

**Edit**: I understand I could zoom in to see the others, but I was hoping to see a dot or the outline or something without doing this.

**Edit 2**: Here's a way to get the desired effect, by plotting the faces using a `PolyCollection` and then the edges using a series of `Line2D` plots with markers, based on Patol75's answer. My application is a `matplotlib` animation with lots of polygons, so I'd prefer to avoid `Line2D` for efficiency, and it would be cleaner if I didn't need to plot things twice, so I'm still hoping for a better answer.

```
ax.add_collection(PolyCollection(verts, lw=3, alpha=0.5, edgecolor=None, facecolor=face_col, zorder=1))

for pts in verts:
    ax.add_line(Line2D([pt[0] for pt in pts], [pt[1] for pt in pts], lw=3, alpha=0.5, color=edge_col,
                                 marker='.', ms=1, mec=edge_col, solid_capstyle='projecting', zorder=2))
```

[image: out_line2d]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zooming in your plotting window, you would notice that your two remaining polygons are being plotted. They are just too small for you to see them. One way to be convinced of this is to replace

```
ax.set_xlim(-1, 6)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
```

by

```
ax.set_xlim(1e-1, 1e1)
ax.set_ylim(1e-5, 1e0)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Your five polygons are now visible, but on the downside the log scale restrains you to the positive side of the axes.
[image]
Now to propose an answer to your problem. If you keep a linear axis, as your polygons sizes span multiple orders of magnitude, you will not be able to see them all. What you can do is add an artist on your plot which specifies their location. This can be done with a marker, an arrow, etc... If we take the example of a marker, as you said, we only want to see this marker if we cannot see the polygon. The keyword zorder in the call to plot() allows to specify which artist should have the display priority on the figure. Please consider the example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
verts = []
for i in range(5):
    w = 0.5 * 10**(-i)
    xs = [i - w, i - w, i + w, i + w, i - w]
    ys = [-w, w, w, -w, -w]
    ax.plot((xs[2] + xs[1]) / 2, (ys[1] + ys[0]) / 2, linestyle='none',
            marker='o', color='xkcd:crimson',  markersize=1, zorder=-1)
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))
ax.set_xlim(-1, 6)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
poly = PolyCollection(verts, lw=5, edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray')
ax.add_collection(poly)
plt.show()
```

which produces
[image]
You would notice that if you zoom on the last two dots in the matplotlib figure, you actually do not see the markers, but rather the polygons.

Comment: It's true that if I zoom in I can see them, but in the real program will be plotting to a file and I won't know the polygon sizes ahead of time. I was hoping for the small ones I could see a dot on the plot, or the outline or something at least.

Comment: Well you can always plot a marker at the center of your polygon for example.

Comment: Finding the center of generic polygons requires extra computation (center of the bounding box can be done by solving 4 linear programs, for example). Also, I would only want the markers to show up when the polygons are not there, otherwise there may be ugly cases where both are visible.

Comment: It's better. The real polygons have alpha values though, so things plotted underneath will show up. The idea of plotting twice once with polys and once with markers seems to work (I'm going to update the question). I'll hold off on awarding the bounty for a few days in case someone comes up with something cleaner / more efficient.

Comment: What you could add is an if condition which calls Line2D only if the polygon is too small. You do that by keeping track of the size of each polygon's edge, and then giving a threshold for the new edge, to determine if it is too small or not.

Answer (score 2):

You may introduce some minimal unit `minw`, which is the smallest size a shape can have.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib import colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
verts = []

edge_col = colors.colorConverter.to_rgb('lime')
face_col = [(2.0 + val) / 3.0 for val in edge_col] # a little lighter

ax.set_xlim(-1, 11)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

u = np.diff(np.array([ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()]), axis=1).min()
px = np.max(fig.get_size_inches())*fig.dpi
minw = u/px/2

for i in range(10):
    w = 0.5 * 10**(-i)
    if w < minw:
        w = minw
    xs = [i - w, i - w, i + w, i - w]
    ys = [-w, w, 0, -w]

    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))


ax.add_collection(PolyCollection(verts, lw=3, alpha=0.5, edgecolor=edge_col, facecolor=face_col))

plt.savefig('out.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The calculation using `get_xlim`, `get_ylim`, `fig.get_size_inches`, and `fig.dpi` is a neat way to do it, but it's a bit of a workaround for the problem. In the real application I'm doing an animation where the axis limits may change, so this wouldn't quite fit in that case. The shapes are also a bit more complicated, though you could compute a bounding box with the vertices and use that for the width.

Comment: You could of course recompute the PolyCollection each time the axis limits change. (Not sure how often that'll be the case?)